# How to end a do while loop after a certain amount of time?

Tags: java

I have written a simple script to output a KeyPress message; it repeats with a do-while loop but never terminates. I want to terminate it after 15 seconds, but none of the commands I've tried have worked. At present, all it does is lock up the executing device with infinite reputations of "HAPPY BIRTHDAY", increasing RAM usage until it crashes. The script is below;

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class robot {

private static boolean yes;

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    yes=(true);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    do {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
} while (yes==true);
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    yes=false;
                }
            }, 
            5000 
    );
}}
```

Advice on either a better loop or how to terminate after a set time is appreciated.

Comment: That timer is not being made until after the loop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? No matter where the timer is, it doesn't work. The program never terminates and I have to use Task Manager to kill it gracelessly.

Comment: Nevermind, thank you; I had to edit the timer to recognize the yes variable as the same one in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to do it, using LocalTime

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
LocalTime later = now.plusSeconds(5);

int count = 0;
while (now.isBefore(later)){
    System.out.println(count++);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    now = LocalTime.now();
}
```

Comment: Thank you; I got the other one to work, but it slips a lot; 1000 ms is actually more like 5000 ms. This one works better and doesn't slip at all.